# Why is my custom annotation logging bean null during autowiring?

Tags: java, spring, annotations

I created a custom annotation for logging following the example [in this blog post](http://jgeeks.blogspot.com/2008/10/auto-injection-of-logger-into-spring.html) almost exactly.  The main difference that I can see is my `LoggerInjector` is annotated with `@Component`.

The annotation works great and I get a non-null Logger instance everywhere except in one case: when I try to log in a method annotated with `@Autowired`.

For example:

```
@Repository
public class MyDao
{
    @AutowiredLogger
    private Logger _logger;

    private JdbcTemplate _jt;

    @Autowired
    public void setDatasource(DataSource ds)
    {
        _logger.debug("Entering setDs")
        _jt = new JdbcTemplate(ds);
        _logger.debut("Exiting setDs);
    }
}
```

A `NullPointerException` is thrown on the first `_logger.debug()` line.

A snippet from applicationContext.xml:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />
<context:component-scan base-package="my.package" />
```

A snippet from dispatch-servlet.xml:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />
<context:component-scan base-package="my.package">
    <context:include-filter type="annotation"
             expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Repository" />
</context:component-scan>
```

How can I have my `@AutowiredLogger` injected before the `@Autowired` methods are run?

Comment: It did, thank you.  I just had a chance to try it out today.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you can control which component gets autowired first. An alternate solution is to use [InitializingBean](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/InitializingBean.html) to configure the class after everything has been set.

You could something like

```
@Override
void afterPropertiesSet() {
    _logger.debug("Entering setDs")
    _jt = new JdbcTemplate(ds);
    _logger.debut("Exiting setDs);
}
```

Comment: I've had a similar issue, although in my cased it was injecting the `ServletContext` - it was null with `@Autowired` and I needed to implement `InitializingBean` and change to setter injection via `afterPropertiesSet`.